# ng-repeat over ng-options that share the same ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I know this is weird.  I'll transform the API Data if this isn't possible.

**But, I need multiple dropdowns to share the same ng-model.**

### **Question:**

1. Why does does `ng-model` unique when it has the same var name?
2. How do I make each drop down share one `ng-model="selectedSize"`

   ```
   <div ng-repeat="(key, val) in listing.colors_and_sizes.data" >
   <p>{{selectedSize}}</p>
    <input
       ng-checked="selected"
       type="radio"
       name="colors"
       ng-model="selected.pdw.color"
       ng-value="key"/>

   <select ng-model="selectedSize"
           ng-options="choice as choice for (idx, choice) in val.sizes.split(',')"
           ng-change="selected.product.set.size(key,val, selectedSize);">
           <option value="">Please select a size</option>
   </select>

   </div>
   ```

Comment: If you use the same ng-model selection in one select will update other select repeated as well with the same value. Is that what you need? ng-repeat creates a child scope so `selected` size is a property on that child scope, so each of them has its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-repeat` creates a child scope so `selectedSize` is a property on that child scope, so each of them will have its own selection. [Read this answer related to child scope inheritance and how it applies to various directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs). If you want to share the same `ng-model` you just need to defined a scope property on your controller.
ex:-

```
 $scope.size = {};
```

and set your ng-model as `ng-model="size.selectedSize"`:

```
<select ng-model="size.selectedSize"
        ng-options="choice as choice for (idx, choice) in val.sizes.split(',')"
        ng-change="selected.product.set.size(key,val, size.selectedSize);">
        <option value="">Please select a size</option>
</select>
```

You do not need to pass the `size.selected` it will be available in your controller as well, but no harm passing it though.

Comment: We really, really need a reference question to close these questions about the dot rule as duplicate…

Comment: @Blackhole Then there wouldnt be all these free points!

Comment: @MatthewHarwood Yep. That's one part of the problem, indeed.

Comment: That was a stupid mistake. I am willing to delete my answer provided, OP unaccepts my answer. I don't need _free points_ :/ (well they are not so free though, there is some effort in it) . you don't get any free points without atleast some little effort. :)

Comment: @PSL I was sincere in my first comment, which was not a critic against you: we really have no reference question about the dot rule, and therefore your answer here is usefull and necessary. ["What are the nuances of…"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs) gives the correct answer but is too broad for all the questions like this one, where the answer is just basically "use the dot rule".